# Azure SQL DB Backup Strategies Clarification

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure

I am in need of some clarification on the best SQL DB backup strategy with regards to Azure. We have developed, deployed and now are now completed with a short-term VS MVC Code First application, but I would like to 'backup' the database, blob storage assets etc...so a year from now we can re-deploy (build up) a working application quickly.

I have exported a .bacpac file and pulled it down local (2MB) but not sure if this file will be able to do a full DB restore in the future (I am not a DB guy per say). NOTE: we plan on disabling all servers/apps/databases/blob storage containers in Azure for this project since our client is unwilling to pay for long term storage or maintenance. So my concern is to make sure the type of backup file is not specific to a server or any other type of Azure dependency.

Ultimately all of these assets will be stored in our source control for usage a year from now.

Any advice/direction would be greatly appreciated. Its a little confusing with what seems to be several differing backup strategies and how they pertain to specific DB centric considerations (pros/cons).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A .bacpac file contains all of the database schema and data and can be re-deployed later, to Azure SQL Database or SQL Server in a VM.  You may also be able to recreate the database from your EF Code-First code through migrations and seeding.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I think this does give me confidence that the .bacpac file should be all we need in future restores. Yes, with code-first we can rebuild the DB, but seeding it was an issue this go-around since no seeding methods were available in app as well as limited documentation...